# PHP: Pull values foreach() nested array, run function, return a 2nd level nested array

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I've got an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [id] => abc
        [name] => Charlotte
        [state] => NC
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
        [id] => def
        [name] => Tampa
        [state] => FL
        )
)
```

What I am trying to do is pull two of the values from each nested array ('id' and 'name'), run a function on them, and return an array that is then nested. So, for each 'id' and 'name,' pass that to "function work($id,$name)," which returns an array, such that the resulting array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [id] => abc
        [name] => Charlotte
        [state] => NC
        [restaurants] => Array (
                               [rname] => Good Burger
                               [rname] => McD
                               )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
        [id] => def
        [name] => Tampa
        [state] => FL
        [restaurants] => Array (
                               [rname] => BK
                               [rname] => White Castle
                               )
        )
)
```

My searches on here found a few ways of pulling the values from the original arrays (foreach() loop), but I am unsure of the best way to pass these values to a function (array_walk doesn't appear to be an option in this case?), and especially of how to return a nested array into another nested array.

Am glad to provide clarification is need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
   $array[$key]['restaurants'] = work($value['id'],$value['name']);
}

function work($id,$name){
    $results = array();
    ///process data
    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
foreach($cities as &$city){
    $city['restaurants'] = work($city['id'],$city['name']);
}
```

[Demo with a dummy function](http://eval.in/32614).

The `&$city` tells PHP that you want to be able to modify the record in your loop (passes the array [by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) instead of as a copy).

After this, you can simply set the `restaurants` value to the array returned by the `work` function.